# iOS app crash on +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState]

Tags: ios, uikit

I got following crash log from Apple.

I thought that this crash occurs during animation. I have tried to solve it by adding following lines but it is not affected.

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO ]
```

Log:

```
Thread : Crashed: WebThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x338fbdf0 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3397acc7 pthread_kill + 62
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x33897909 abort + 76
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x33925331 szone_size + 394
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x33288621 object_dispose + 20
5  UIKit                          0x2828cd8f -[UIViewAnimationState dealloc] + 174
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x33299d5f objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 166
7  UIKit                          0x2828ae15 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 340
8  MediaPlayer                    0x264a6d07 -[MPVolumeSlider _layoutForAvailableRoutes] + 1322
9  MediaPlayer                    0x264a592d -[MPVolumeSlider layoutSubviews] + 60
10 UIKit                          0x28255fd3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 546
11 QuartzCore                     0x27c69d29 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 128
12 QuartzCore                     0x27c6555d CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
13 UIKit                          0x28268bb3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 138
14 UIKit                          0x2826e053 -[UISlider setValue:animated:] + 178
15 MediaPlayer                    0x264a5ffb -[MPVolumeSlider volumeController:volumeValueDidChange:] + 78
16 MediaPlayer                    0x265249c5 -[MPVolumeController updateVolumeValue] + 252
17 MediaPlayer                    0x264a5a3b -[MPVolumeSlider didMoveToSuperview] + 126
18 UIKit                          0x28254e71 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 428
19 UIKit                          0x2825f6db -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1498
20 UIKit                          0x2825f0fb -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
21 MediaPlayer                    0x264a8841 -[MPVolumeView _createSubviews] + 236
22 MediaPlayer                    0x264a748d -[MPVolumeView _initWithStyle:] + 212
23 MediaPlayer                    0x264a7521 -[MPVolumeView initWithFrame:style:] + 80
24 MediaPlayer                    0x264a74cb -[MPVolumeView initWithFrame:] + 38
25 UIKit                          0x282760c9 -[UIView init] + 44
26 WebCore                        0x313b6675 -[WebMediaSessionHelper allocateVolumeView] + 264
27 WebCore                        0x313b6927 -[WebMediaSessionHelper initWithCallback:] + 394
28 WebCore                        0x313b5a51 WebCore::MediaSessionManageriOS::MediaSessionManageriOS() + 172
29 WebCore                        0x313b593d WebCore::MediaSessionManager::sharedManager() + 124
30 WebCore                        0x313b4b8d WebCore::MediaSession::MediaSession(WebCore::MediaSessionClient&) + 32
31 WebCore                        0x31044b65 WebCore::HTMLMediaSession::create(WebCore::MediaSessionClient&) + 20
32 WebCore                        0x31033487 WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::HTMLMediaElement(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, bool) + 1046
33 WebCore                        0x3105c60b WebCore::HTMLVideoElement::create(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, bool) + 38
34 WebCore                        0x310265d5 WebCore::videoConstructor(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, WebCore::HTMLFormElement*, bool) + 56
35 WebCore                        0x31025d29 WebCore::HTMLElementFactory::createElement(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, WebCore::HTMLFormElement*, bool) + 232
36 WebCore                        0x30c2df9d WebCore::HTMLDocument::createElement(WTF::AtomicString const&, int&) + 88
37 WebCore                        0x30c2dedf WebCore::jsDocumentPrototypeFunctionCreateElement(JSC::ExecState*) + 242
38 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606e133 llint_entry + 21314
39 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606dcd9 llint_entry + 20200
40 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606dcd9 llint_entry + 20200
41 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606dd27 llint_entry + 20278
42 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606dd27 llint_entry + 20278
43 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606dd27 llint_entry + 20278
44 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606dd27 llint_entry + 20278
45 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606dd27 llint_entry + 20278
46 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606de2d llint_entry + 20540
47 JavaScriptCore                 0x2606de2d llint_entry + 20540
48 JavaScriptCore                 0x26068bdf callToJavaScript + 334
49 JavaScriptCore                 0x25ff83b5 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 36
50 JavaScriptCore                 0x25e2e753 JSC::Interpreter::execute(JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 5738
51 JavaScriptCore                 0x25e2cf9b JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::JSValue*) + 358
52 WebCore                        0x314e9b29 WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld&) + 196
53 WebCore                        0x30c48e7b WebCore::ScriptController::evaluate(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 26
54 WebCore                        0x30c48e1f WebCore::ScriptElement::executeScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 234
55 WebCore                        0x30c2ee53 WebCore::ScriptElement::prepareScript(WTF::TextPosition const&, WebCore::ScriptElement::LegacyTypeSupport) + 754
56 WebCore                        0x30cc88b3 WebCore::HTMLScriptRunner::runScript(WebCore::Element*, WTF::TextPosition const&) + 202
57 WebCore                        0x30cc87a3 WebCore::HTMLScriptRunner::execute(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Element>, WTF::TextPosition const&) + 34
58 WebCore                        0x30cc8735 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::runScriptsForPausedTreeBuilder() + 52
59 WebCore                        0x30c7094f WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::canTakeNextToken(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode, WebCore::PumpSession&) + 50
60 WebCore                        0x30c6fedd WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::pumpTokenizer(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode) + 344
61 WebCore                        0x30cd0f3f WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::resumeParsingAfterScriptExecution() + 78
62 WebCore                        0x30ccf9f1 non-virtual thunk to WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::notifyFinished(WebCore::CachedResource*) + 72
63 WebCore                        0x30ccca8b WebCore::CachedResource::checkNotify() + 58
64 WebCore                        0x30ccc895 WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 128
65 CFNetwork                      0x2462fc8f ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 78
66 CFNetwork                      0x246cd365 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 60
67 CFNetwork                      0x24620985 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 60
68 CoreFoundation                 0x24aebc6d CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
69 CFNetwork                      0x2462083f RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 182
70 CFNetwork                      0x24620705 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 216
71 CFNetwork                      0x24620599 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
72 CoreFoundation                 0x24ba1faf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
73 CoreFoundation                 0x24ba1451 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 364
74 CoreFoundation                 0x24b9fa25 __CFRunLoopRun + 772
75 CoreFoundation                 0x24aec201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
76 CoreFoundation                 0x24aec013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
77 WebCore                        0x30c8c063 RunWebThread(void*) + 418
78 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x33979e23 _pthread_body + 138
79 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x33979d97 _pthread_start + 118
80 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x33977b20 thread_start + 8
```